# What is the best way in React Native to store global app data used in many screens?

Tags: reactjs, database, firebase, react-native

I am making a React Native app and I need the user data (fetched from firebase database) to be available right after the first screen and in many other screens.

As it is complete user object data, I do not think passing it via the navigator props is suitable. So I am searching for alternatives.
Can someone help ?

Comment: Local storage wouldbe a solution

Comment: The problem with Async storage is the following: As soon as the user is logged in, i am able to get his data and save it in the Async storage, but to use it in the next screen i have to do AsyncStorage.get() but it is asynchronous and i can't have asynchronous functional components

Comment: The functional component can't be async, but you can do async things within components, otherwise they wouldn't be very useful.  Something like `useEffect(() => { AsyncStorage.getItem('name').then(name => setName(name) }, [])`.  You should search for React Native state management solutions - Redux, Zustand, etc

Comment: @Abe Thanks I have been doing almost exactly like this, except I did not use the then callback which made it useless.

Comment: Does the await  method like https://blog.jscrambler.com/how-to-use-react-native-asyncstorage not also work in functional thing?

Comment: @StefanBD it does

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way to store and share global data is Context API or Global Context .

This new API solves one major problem–prop drilling.  Prop drilling is the processing of getting data from component A to component Z by passing it through multiple layers of intermediary React components. The component will receive props indirectly . Context provides a way to pass data through the component tree without having to pass props down manually at every level.

To create a context, we use React.createContext which creates a context object. You can pass in anything as an argument to React.createContext.

import React from "react";

const YourContext = React.createContext("value");

To make this context available to all our React components, we have to use a Provider.
Every context object comes with a Provider React component that allows consuming components to subscribe to context changes. It is the provider that allows the context to be consumed by other components.

In order to create a provider, we have to import our Context.